# Capitalizing every first word after a period in a Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, string

I'm trying to capitalize the first letter (and ONLY the first one) of a new sentence in some body text stored in a Pandas DF.

Example: my dataframe has a Description column which may contain text like:

> This product has several different features. **it** is also **VERY** cost
> effective. **it** is one of my favorite products.

I want my result to look like:

> This product has several different features. **It** is also **very** cost
> effective. **It** is one of my favorite products.

.capitalize() doesn't work for me because it leaves new sentences in the same body text with lowercase (that is, whatever comes after a dot and a space ". ".

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this without iterating through the rows manually?

Thanks for your time,

Comment: Do the answers to this question solve your problem: [Capitalize the first word of a sentence in a text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54602252/1609514)?

Comment: [This might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800401/how-to-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-every-sentence)

Answer (score 0):

re.findIter will return all the matches of a regex (in our case the .)

and you can just use to lower before it.

example (may not work as is didn't have an IDE handy):

```py
mystring = "SOOOme wEirdly capiTalised STRINg. Followed By CHARACTERS"
mystring = myString.lower()
matches = re.finditer('[.]')
for match in matches:
  mystring[match.pos] = mystring[match.pos].upper()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your sentences end/start with dot and space characters: `". "` you can use `split` and `join` together with `capitalize`:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {'index' :[1, 2], "description": ["This product has several different features. it is also VERY cost effective. it is one of my favorite products.", "test sentence. another SENTENCE"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["description"].apply(lambda x: ". ".join([sentence.capitalize() for sentence in x.lower().split(". ")]))
```

If you would want to cover more complex cases, then you can use `nltk` or `spacy` tokenizers to split the sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to get the sentences and map `capitalize` on them using `str.replace`:

```
df['capitalize'] = df["description"].str.replace(r'[a-zA-Z][^.]+', lambda m: m.group().capitalize(), regex=True)
```

Example output:

```
              description              capitalize
0  Abc def. gHi JKL. mno.  Abc def. Ghi jkl. Mno.
```

Used input:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {"description": ["Abc def. gHi JKL. mno."]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Regex:

```
[a-zA-Z]  # match a letter
[^.]+     # match anything but a period
```