# How to capitalize the first letter of sentences in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that will capitalize the first letter of the sentence that the user inputs

```
strEnter = str(input("Enter sentences to be modified: "))
strSentence = ""
sentence = list(strEnter.split(". "))
for i in range(len(sentence)):
    sentence[i] = sentence[i].strip()
    sentence[i] = sentence[i].strip(".")
    sentence[i] = sentence[i][:1].upper() + sentence[i][1:]
    strSentence = ". ".join(sentence) + "."

    print("Your modified sentence is:", strSentence)
    print()

    strChoice = str(input("Enter 'y' to try again... "))
    strEnter = str(input("Enter sentences to be modified: "))
else:
    print("Thank you for using this application")
```

when I try this code it doesn't work the first time but the second time around it will capitalize the first letters and I'm not sure how to fix this, this is my output below.

```
Enter sentences to be modified: my name is Samantha. i am a teacher.
Your modified sentence is: My name is Samantha. i am a teacher..

Enter 'y' to try again... y
Enter sentences to be modified: my name is Samantha. i am a teacher.
Your modified sentence is: My name is Samantha. I am a teacher.
```

Comment: [Capitalize the first word of a sentence in a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54602252/), [How to capitalize the first letter of every sentence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22800401)

Answer (score 0):

The logic is not flowing how you want it to flow. Consider this rework:

```
strEnter = str(input("Enter sentences to be modified: "))
strSentence = ""
sentence = list(strEnter.split(". "))

strChoice = 'y'

while strChoice == 'y':
    for i in range(len(sentence)):
        sentence[i] = sentence[i].strip()
        sentence[i] = sentence[i].strip(".")
        sentence[i] = sentence[i][:1].upper() + sentence[i][1:]
        strSentence = ". ".join(sentence) + "."

    print("Your modified sentence is:", strSentence)
    print()

    strChoice = str(input("Enter 'y' to try again... "))
    if strChoice!='y':
        break
    strEnter = str(input("Enter sentences to be modified: "))

print("Thank you for using this application")
```